# Multithread em aplicação web

Tags: java, thread, multithreading, aplicação-web

Tenho uma aplicação que faz alguns processamentos no servidor e depois entrega para o cliente.
Algo como:

```
    http://aplicacao:8080/app/videos/extrair/{id}.
```

Onde o "id" é a referencia do item para processamento.

Se usuário repetir a requisição 10 vezes com itens diferentes, ele está criando 10 threads simultâneas. mas gostaria de criar apenas 3 threads simultâneas para cada usuário, e quando essas 3 acabarem, comecem as 3 próximas da fila. Para não sobrecarregar o servidor.

Não estou conseguindo implementar com ThreadPoolExecutor no servidor web, porque sempre que é feita uma nova requisição ele instancia a classe de novo. Pensei em implementar um singleton, mas eu teria que criar as threads por usuário, ou IP diferente.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Podes ter uma *stack* para cada usuário, com o máximo de x *threads*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para não recriar a `ThreadPoolExecutor` a cada requisição, coloque-a na sessão do usuário.

Exemplo:

```java
//valida requisição
//...

ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = null;

//evita problemas com duas requisições simultâneas do mesmo usuário
synchonized (session) {
    tpe = session.get("userThreadPool");
    if (tpe == null) {
        tpe = MeuThreadPoolBuilder.criarNovoThreadPool();
        session.put("userThreadPool", tpe);
    }
}

//adiciona processo no pool
//...
```

O problema dessa abordagem é que ela não funciona em *clusters*, i.e., se houver mais de um servidor com a aplicação.

O ideal para execução de processos em filas é ter algum tipo de *scheduler*, como o [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), que é um agendador com suporte a ambientes distribuídos.

Além disso, definir *threads* por usuário pode sobrecarregar facilmente o servidor e se tornar um problema se o número de usuários aumentar. Em resumo: sua aplicação não vai escalar.

O ideal é definir um número máximo de *threads* global e então enfileirar todas as requisições de processamento nesta fila.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Gostaria de saber se existe uma quantidade ideal de threads, para que não sobrecarregue o servidor. Isso depende muito da configuração de hardware do servidor?

Comment: @RicardoFarias Sim, depende muito da configuração do servidor, afinal se você colocar mais threads do que CPUs, *pode* haver muito *overhead* de troca de processos. Isso também depende se houverem outros processos sendo executados além do seu sistema. Já li em algum lugar que pelo menos uma CPU deveria ser deixada exclusivamente para o sistema operacional, mas não sou especialista em configuração de servidores. O ideal, no entanto, é fazer testes de desempenho com o sistema e ver como ele se comporta melhor.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor solução seria criar uma stack para cada usuário, e limitar todas elas para executar somente 3 threads de uma vez, e colocar o resto no `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Deste modo, como a stack não vai deixar de existir até todos os seus threads serem executados, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` não será chamada novamente quando uma nova requisição for feita.

Answer (score 0):

Esta sua necessidade tem muita cara de "actors" como erlang, clojure, scala ou akka (agora padrão do scala mas com implementação em java também).

Existem outros modelos de concorrência também, você pode ir para o apache storm, tem uma aplicação utilizando e é muito rápida, neste caso você pode controlar o número de spouts ( geradores de dados ) para os bolts ou ter um só spout e a quantidade de bolts para cada "cliente" que quiser. No meu caso eu tenho 10 bolts que ficam gravando em banco de dados na última camada so storm. As possibilidades do storm são infinitas mas ele é recomendado para clusters, recomendado, utilizo em uma máquina só e tenho um problema com os dados do zookeeper dele que entopem o meu tmpfs.

Se não importar quantas threads você quiser utilizar e sua apliacação for em 1 servidor, então pode pensar no disruptor da lmax, praticamente o disruptor tenta mantar o dado quente ou seja, na memória cache do processador. Por um acaso vai ser a próxima evolução da minha aplicação que citei.

Estude bastante, muito mesmo todas as possibilidade que citei, pelo simples fato delas conterem uma menor complexidade acidental do que ficar tentando manipular threads, não há problemas nisso, mas quanto menos precisarmos ir ao nível mais baixo de tudo, com uma ótima relação custo benefício, é melhor.

Vá com calma nas possibilidades de tudo na vida, mantenha sua aplicação rodando do jeito que esta, faça os patchs só para evitar seu medo de sobrecarregar o servidor e pule para uma solução de mais alto nível, "talvez" até uma nova linguage se for o caso... a melhor solução é aquela que é melhor para você e o negócio.